Is my question hard or just niche?
I asked this question a few days ago and bountied it this morning. I've got around 50 views but the only feedback I've had is one comment.
I don't know enough about the topic to tell whether it's a hard question. I can't find any mention of the three dimensional case online, so there might be some trivial solution.
If I don't get any answers in a week, I'm thinking I might move it to Mathoverflow. I've seen a similar question there answering the question in the case of polygons. Would this be appropriate if it is a difficult question?
Or maybe it's just a niche question about a small topic?
As of 02-May-2024 I have followed Gerry Myerson's advice and posted a copy of my question on Mathoverflow.

In my experience questions that aren't on the well-beaten track of: integrals or elementary analysis/calculus/group theory/diff. geometry and physics need to be intrinsically very interesting recreational questions or of appeal to experts, in order to get attention. It's a popularity contest between the dominant forces, active experts and confused undergraduates. It's very very easy for a question to fall by the wayside; something of a graduate level, say, that isn't quite expert or quite accessible to the average reader gets little attention.

FWIW I looked at the question a couple days ago. I found it interesting, so I upvoted. Alas, not my area of expertise, and I couldn't make any headway with it using techniques outside my main interest areas either. I simply second the advice in Gerry's answer. The question is interesting, but may be very difficult. After all, the paper on the 2D versions is from 2011, so very recent by my standards!

Answer: It's hard. I also think you will get interest on MO.  But most likely they'll point you to relevant references.

My impression is that this question is relatively hard (certainly not standard undergraduate fare) and also pretty niche. The combination of those two factors probably explains the paucity of answers.

I think it would be a good question for MathOverflow, but

I would let the bounty on math.stack run out first,
I wouldn't "move it" to MO, that is, I wouldn't delete it from math.stack,
I'd be sure to leave a link at math.stack to the question at MO, and put a link at MO to the question at math.stack.


This is the way to do it! As long there is a gap between ask on mse and overflow then one isn't spamming, and casting a wider net is definitely useful. Also the failure to get it answered with bounty on mse will usually lead to better reception on overflow (it's had time to simmer).  I really wish other sites on the stackexchange network were more receptive to this appropriate cross-posting of questions, when a question can FIT and fails to achieve answers in good faith at its first (or n^th) site. 
