Should I / How can I move a bountied question to math overflow?
I posted this question a week ago and have since bountied it. I still haven't figured out the answer to the problem. I'm starting to think that it might be a research level question and would be more appropriate in mathoverflow.
Should I move this question to mathoverflow? The bounty for the question
expires tomorrow.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/ might be a better destination

Related: Can a question with an open bounty on it be migrated from M.SE to MO? On [meta.se]: What happens to a bounty question if it gets migrated? and Should we be able to vote to move bounty questions to another site?

You may want to read my answer at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37428/is-my-question-hard-or-just-niche

@MatthewTowers:  It looks like the OP has already asked something of the kind at CrossValidated without much result.

I believe you'll need to wait for the bounty to expire before it can be migrated (or closed).
